# SQL correlated query + department average

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, correlated-subquery, adventureworks

I am new on this, so a little about my aspirations :

I am technical engineer, and wanting to improve my SQL skills, and get to advanced/master level for the purpose of going down the business analyst route, leveraging data analysis to give me an advantage in the role.

I have just about go my head around correlated sub queries, ableit confusing termonology, and 9/10 being able to mentally remember what to write(not without trial and error), anyway my problem/question is as below:

I am using the adventure works DB and am using the below script to return workers who have a rate above the avg for their department

```
select Concat(v_dep.FirstName, ' ', v_dep.LastName) as Full_name, eph.Rate
from HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartment v_dep
join HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory eph
on v_dep.BusinessEntityID = eph.BusinessEntityID
where eph.Rate > (select AVG(eph2.rate)
                  from HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartment v_dep2
                  join HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory eph2
                  on v_dep2.BusinessEntityID = eph2.BusinessEntityID
                  where v_dep2.Department = v_dep.Department);
```

However, what I want to do for comparative purposes is have an additional column next to their rate, showing me the average rate for the department they belong to. I have been trolling through the web trying to construct a concise question to encapsulate what I have described but have been struggling.

Any advice would be great !

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It is time you learned about window functions:

```
select x.*
from (select Concat(v_dep.FirstName, ' ', v_dep.LastName) as Full_name,
             eph.rate,
             avg(eph.rate) over (partition by v_dep.BusinessEntityID) as avg_rate
      from HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartment v_dep join
           HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory eph
           on v_dep.BusinessEntityID = eph.BusinessEntityID
     ) x
where rate > avg_rate;
```

Note:  I'm not intimately familiar with the database.  However, a table with the name `EmployeePayHistory` sounds like it has multiple rows per employee.  If so, you probably want to filter based on the time or the "current" rate.

Comment: Hi Gordon,

I tried running this but it errored on the X outside of the bracket, at the end. Any ideas why ? (i must be missing the obvious, so sorry !)

Comment: @sql_journey93 . . . That is a table alias, part of standard SQL, and support by pretty much every database.  Does the error message have more information?  Actually, the problem may have been a typo -- `rate` was selected twice in the subquery.